# Can I use the click event listener in mobile application with js? Or should I stick to touchstart

Tags: javascript, touch, dom-events, addeventlistener, event-listener

I have a website that I'm working on! And it's a mobile-first website and now I'm implementing the clicks on mobile (touches).

Now, since this is my first responsive website ever I don't know if I should use the `click` eventListener or should I stick with `touchstart` event? Here is an example of what I have in my code:

```
menuCancel.addEventListener("touchstart", () => {
  menu.classList.remove("u-d-none");
  menuCancel.classList.add("u-d-none");
});
```

It works great but only on mobiles.

If I use it like that will it work on mobiles without errors that I don't know about?

```
menuCancel.addEventListener("click", () => {
  menu.classList.remove("u-d-none");
  menuCancel.classList.add("u-d-none");
});
```

Comment: It's pretty standard to use `click` across all web platforms. Even though the user is not using a mouse, the event will still kick off the standard mouse events (`mousedown`, `mouseup`, `click`).

Comment: @AustinEzell Thanks for that! Using it, now